# Trying to write a matrix multiplier for arbitrary-sized matrices

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

Trying to write a matrix-multiplying function for arbitrary-sized matrices in C.  I'm trying the following for my function signature:

```
void matrixMult(void *A, int Xa, int Ya, void *B, int Xb, int Yb);
```

(it's returning void for now while I troubleshoot it, I'll make a proper return later once I have it working the way I want it to)

The X and Y parameters are intended to inform the function of the dimensions of the incoming arrays (from my understanding, that's necessary, since in C arrays don't know their own size).  So I'm passing in two void pointers A and B, as well as their dimensions.

**My question:**  Once I'm in the function, how do I go about casting the void pointers back to int arrays so I can read them?  I tried the following:

```
(int)*A[someX][someY]
```

, but I get a compiler error about "invalid use of void pointer".

---

**EDIT**

The following is my full function for now (updating as I'm troubleshooting it):

```
#pragma warning(disable: 8057)
#include <stdio.h>

void matrixMult(int **A, int Xa, int Ya, int **B, int Xb, int Yb);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //   [x][y] x--> row; y-->cols
    int a[3][5] = {
          {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 }
        , { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 }
        , {  4,  8, 15, 16, 23 }
    };
    int b[5][7] = {
          {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7 }
        , { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 }
        , {  4,  8, 15, 16, 23, 42,  0 }
        , {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7 }
        , { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 }
    };

    matrixMult((int **)a, 3, 5, (int **)b, 5, 7);

    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}

void matrixMult(int **A, int Xa, int Ya, int **B, int Xb, int Yb) {
    printf("starting matrix mult\n");
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<Xa; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<Ya; j++) {
            //printf("%i, %i:\t", i, j);
            printf("%i\t", A[Ya*i+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**  Thanks for the tips and resources guys!  The version posted above works as I expect it to now, but I'm afraid it's an ugly bastardization of how pointers are SUPPOSED to be used.  For now I'm off to do some more reading on pointers (thanks cnicutar!), and I'll revisit this later.  Any further criticism of my latest version is appreciated, but I'm marking this answered and moving on to do some further reading for now.  Thanks again!

Comment: With that signature, you can't use double array notation because the compiler has no idea how large the array rows are. You will have to use pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `int[5][7]` is more like `int*` than `int**`. Change your function to `int*` and use `a[x+y*width]` when accessing elements.

Comment: @Banthar But that would be UB? Not to mention unclear.

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think there is any other way to dynamically access static multidimensional array.

Comment: Since his number of dimensions is constant (2D), it will always be a double pointer.

Comment: @Daniel: That's not how it works. In memory `int[5][7]` is the same as `int[5*7]` it contains no pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If I understand you question correctly** you could do something like

```
int **a = A;
```

Why are you using `void *` and not `int **A` straight away ?

#### EDIT 1

In light of comment below: see [this FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ary2dfunc3.html) (`f3` is what you want). And also [this one](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html).

#### Edit 2

Declare and initialize them (something) like this:

```
int **a;

a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * 3);
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
}
```

Comment: Using void * because I'm inexperienced @ C  :-}  What I wanted was a way to pass an array of arbitrary size.  So I could just change the sig. to use int **A, then, to pass the arrays in?  Trying now...

Comment: No, you can't pass n-dimensional arrays of arbitrary size. You can pass pointers :-)

Comment: Reading that FAQ now; see my edit above; now I'm using  int **A in the sig, and &a in the call to the function;  I'm getting an incompatible type error in the compiler.  Thanks for the FAQ link! EDIT: Doh!  The incompat. type error was because I didn't update the function definition, too.

Comment: @loneboat Read up on those, and read http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html. Actually reading all the list someday will do wonders (it does for me).

Comment: Thanks so much for those - I think you've set me on the right track!  I've been in PHP lala land for several years, and am trying to pick C back up.

Comment: Current version (above) compiles with no complaints, but crashes when I try to read an int;

Comment: @loneboat You can't cast arrays like that. Use `malloc` (Q 6.16). See my edit.

Comment: See latest edit above; thanks for your help!  Also, your malloc() solution looks great, I'll have a look at that when I get home tonight (at work now, getting ready to leave).  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Prototype must be a double pointer.  Also you don't need to de-reference (unless your inner most pointer IS a pointer itself) since you are casting it to an int.  Unless the type was int *.

```
void matrixMult(void **A, int Xa, int Ya, void **B, int Xb, int Yb);
```

No need to de-reference since it's just a basic int.

```
(int)A[someX][someY]
```

If you had, let's say an int * you would need to dereference it, but even then you would dereference outside of the cast

```
*(int *)A[someX][someY]
```

You must let the compiler know what the type is before you can dereference the pointer.  Otherwise you'll get an error of trying to dereference a void *.

Comment: Or he could just tuse an int** and save himself the cast.

Answer (score 2):

If you have C99 you can simply use variable length arrays for that, they are made for it. Forget about pointers to pointers and just do

```
void matrixMult(size_t n, size_t m, size_t k, double A[n][m], double B[m][k], double C[n][k]);
```

Important here is that the sizes are first in the parameter list such that they are known when it comes to `A`, `B` and `C`. Inside your function you can just access the individual matrix elements by something like `A[i][j]`.

Then to allocate such matrices, you have to be a bit careful that you don't allocated them on the stack. E.g

```
double (*A)[n][m] = malloc(*A);
```

should do.

Really try to forget about defining matrices as array of pointers, where for each pointer you'd have to allocate its own chunk and so on. This much to complicated, error prone and adds an unnecessary level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

`void*` is not some kind of template type parameter. Since you need to cast the pointer to some type, namely the type of the data the pointer points to, and the whole operations are compiled against that type, using a `void*` pointer alone makes only very little sense here. Either add a parameter telling which kind of type is passed, and branch in the function accordingly, or better use proper types and name the functions accordingly. Also you should not use double pointers: depending on memory allocation it may break cache locality.

To save typing use macros:

```
#define MATRIXMULT(type, typeshort) void matrixMult##typeshort(\
##type *A, int const Xa, int const Ya, ##type *B, int const Xb, int const Yb)\
{ \
    printf("starting matrix mult\n"); \
    int i, j, k; \
\
    if(Ya != Xb || Xa != Yb) \
        return; // dimensions don't match \
\
    for (i=0; i<Xa; i++) { \
        for (j=0; j<Ya; j++) { \
            A[i*Ya + j]=0; \
            for(k=0; k < Xa; k++) \
                A[i*Ya + j] += A[i*Ya + k] * B[k*Yb + j]; \
    } \
}

MATRIXMULT(double, d)
MATRIXMULT(float, f)
MATRIXMULT(int, i)
```

**EDIT due to comment:**

`MATRIXMULT(double, d)` expands to

```
void matrixMultd(
double *A, int const Xa, int const Ya, double *B, int const Xb, int const Yb)
{ 
    printf("starting matrix mult\n"); 
    int i, j, k; 

    if(Ya != Xb || Xa != Yb) 
        return;

    for (i=0; i<Xa; i++) { 
        for (j=0; j<Ya; j++) { 
            A[i*Ya + j]=0; 
            for(k=0; k < Xa; k++) 
                A[i*Ya + j] += A[i*Ya + k] * B[k*Yb + j]; 
    } 
}
```

So using macros it's very easy to get the same function in multiple variants. With above macro expansions you can call `matrixMultd`, `matrixMultf` and `matrixMulti`

Comment: Interesting - could you elaborate a bit on how the macros work in this?  I don't use macros much, but it looks handy.  Thanks!

Comment: @loneboat: It's just a littlebit of preprocessor magic. When writing MATRIXMULT at this place the content of the macro is pasted, putting the macro parameters whereever they appear in the macro. ## is token concatenation, so what you write in the parameter gets concatenated there.